# RealTime Calculatiosn with AngularJS

Tags: function, angularjs

I'm very new to Angularjs and the MVVM model in general.  I'm trying to build a calculator app that works the way an excell spreadsheet might.  IE updating one cell causes all the dependent cells to also update.

So far my code looks like this

```
<div ng-app="">


<div ng-controller="calculations">

    <input type="number" name="staff" ng-model="staff" id="staff" ng-change="change('C3')"  />

    <input type="hidden" name="budget" ng-model="budget" ng-change="change('C6')" placeholder="budget" />

    <input type="text" name="total" ng-model="total" ng-change="change('C8')" />

</div>
```

and the Angular

```
function calculations($scope) {







$scope.change = function (cell) {

    if (cell == 'C3') {
        $scope.budget = $scope.staff * 35000;

    }






};

}
```

What I don't know how to do is add a joining function that when cell = C6 (which it should $scope.budget is set in my first function) then $scope.total = $scope.budget / $scope.staff; and so on until all my fields have dynamic values.  The idea is that I don't want to have to do a submit or click to begin the calculations, I want to do them on the fly which is why I chose angular because it's my understanding that this is what it does well.  Thoughts?

Comment: Does 'total' need to be editable? I think this would be ridiculously easy if 'staff' and 'budget' were the only editable fields, and 'total' was dynamically calculated off of those (but uneditable itself).

Comment: don't worry which cell triggers `$scope.change()`, just run the calcs for `total`

Comment: Wow that was so much easier than I thought, charlietfl if you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it :D THANKS